# 'from' attribute missing in ejabberd offline message Packet

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I'm trying to write a module, which triggers a HTTP POST to an API when a user receives an offline message in ejabberd. It's for an iOS app which supports Push notifications.

I followed the guide on http://jasonrowe.com/2011/12/30/ejabberd-offline-messages/

I tested the code in the blog post. Most parts are working, but the `from` attribute is missing in the intercepted offline message. As you can see in the above blog post, the author's screen shot has the same problem, too. So, how can I get the sender's account name in an offline message Packet?

Did I miss something or is it a bug (in offline message, `from` attribute is just missing)?

BTW, I configured shared roster 'Everyone' in my ejabberd config, which allows everyone to see everyone as 'contacts'. I'm not sure if it's the reason.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Please use the below blog , it is very simple and usful, it is works fine for me.

http://symmetricinfinity.com/2013/01/23/ios-push-notifications-from-ejabberd.html

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue and change the message package in Client code will fix this. Simple add 'from' attribute to it :)